# How can I "zero" an object's orientation in blender?

Tags: transforms, coordinates

So I want to change the reference "zero" orientation [with respect to the global coordinate system] of a body in blender.  In other words, when a body's rotation is set to zero (0 deg, 0 deg, 0 deg), the body's axis is oriented in a certain direction.  I want to change this "zeroed" direction without changing the actual rotation.  For example, how could I rotate this body 90 deg about the x-axis [with respect to the global coordinate system] and have the rotation coordinates still say (0 deg, 0 deg, 0deg)?

Comment: Rotate it in Edit mode or apply the rotation

Comment: Congrats on the 10,000th question on our site!

Answer (score 12):

The simplest ways to do this are to either rotate the mesh in *Edit Mode* or to rotate it in *Object mode* and then applying the rotation.

So you can either enter *Edit mode*, by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and then rotating the mesh with <kbd>R</kbd>; the reason this works is that, when transforms are applied in *edit mode*, the object's *origin* is not affected.

The other possible solution is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>>*Rotation*, which will, essentially do the same as above, by rotating the mesh, but not the object, and thus not the origin, and then resseting the origin's roattion.

Answer (score 8):

You want to apply the rotation. Select your object, then go to *Object > Apply > Rotation*.

This should do what you want to do